# How to add a selection dropdown dependant from another?

Tags: php, symfony

I've a form with 2 dropdown lists. The first one with molecule families  and the second with molecule subgroup. When someone choose a family, he should only see the subgroups related to this family in the second dropdown.

[image]

**My Form Type**:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('Families', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices' => array(
                'Monosaccharides' => 'Monosaccharides',
                'Oligosaccharides ' => 'Oligosaccharides ',
                'Polysaccharides' => 'Polysaccharides'
            ),
            'placeholder' => 'Choose an option',
            'required' => false
        ))
        ->add('MolecularGroups', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices' => array(
                'Monosaccharide' => 'Monosaccharide',
                'Oligosaccharide' => 'Oligosaccharide',
                'Cyanogenic glycoside' => 'Cyanogenic glycoside'
            ),
            'placeholder' => 'Choose an option',
            'required' => false
        ));
}
```

Can someone show me the Symfony documentation about how to implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Question:

> Can someone show me a documentation on how to do that?

The Documentation references:

- [How to Dynamically Modify Forms Using Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)
- [Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Thanks again for the edit, my english is not so good as i think ... french here ^^